# Getting values from SQL table in Evoq (DotNetNuke), DNN custom Module

Tags: sql, database, content-management-system, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I am not so familiar with c# or asp.net. If you have a solution, please keep this in mind when explaining.

I am using DNN and Evoq. I have created a new module using Module Creator. I need to access my table (Test_Table). This table is internal it's part of DNN/Evoq database.
I can access it when i go to Evoq (CMS), settings, SQL Console. (Example: Select * from Test_Table) The table is set up correctly.

These are the starter files I got when i created the module:
View.ascx, View.ascx.cs and In App_LocalResources View.ascx

My Question.

How do i get the table values for Test_Table, a table that is not external but part of DNN/Evoq database. There is also no security / login requirements for this table.

Code on: View.ascx.cs

```
#region Using Statements

using System;
using DotNetNuke.Entities.Modules;

#endregion

namespace TestFormSupport1.MyTestFormSupport1
{

public partial class View : PortalModuleBase
{

    #region Event Handlers

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);

        cmdSave.Click += cmdSave_Click;
        cmdCancel.Click += cmdCancel_Click;
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
                         txtField.Text = (string)Settings["field"];
        }
    }
    
    protected void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ModuleController.Instance.UpdateModuleSetting(ModuleId, "field", txtField.Text);
        DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.AddModuleMessage(this, "Update Successful 3", DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls.ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.GreenSuccess);
    }


    protected void cmdCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #endregion

}
```

}

Code on View.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="TestFormSupport1.MyTestFormSupport1.View" CodeFile="View.ascx.cs" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="Label" Src="~/controls/LabelControl.ascx" %>

<div class="dnnForm dnnEdit dnnClear" id="dnnEdit">

<fieldset>

    <div class="dnnFormItem">

        <dnn:label id="plField" runat="server" text="Field" helptext="Enter a value" controlname="txtField" />

        <asp:textbox id="txtField" runat="server" maxlength="255" />

    </div>

  </fieldset>

   <ul class="dnnActions dnnClear">

    <li><asp:linkbutton id="cmdSave" text="Save" runat="server" cssclass="dnnPrimaryAction" /></li>

    <li><asp:linkbutton id="cmdCancel" text="Cancel" runat="server" cssclass="dnnSecondaryAction" /></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a solution but, you need to get a copy of Mitchell Sellers’ book “DotNetNuke Module Programming” and a copy of Chris Hammond’s module development templates.  Those townresources will provide what you need to know.

Comment: Thanks Joe, any advice is appreciated. I will take a look at the books you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

DNN has different possibilities to access data - DAL, DAL+ and [DAL2](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/dal-2) (which is the "newest" one). To find an example read [Using DAL 2 in a real world module](https://www.bitboxx.net/Blog/Post/190#/).